# PHP preg_match 1 string 2 digit validation

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

value: `a11b22c33`

I want to validate above value with preg_match with 1 string and 2 numbers

```
preg_match('/^\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}\s{1}\d{2}$/', $value)
```

I tried but it didn't work.

Comment: You never need `{1}`. Everything matches once unless you quantify it.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
preg_match('/^([a-z]\d{2}){3}$/', $value)
```

`\s` matches whitespace, `[a-z]` matches lowercase letters. If you also need uppercase letters, add the `i` modifier after the second `/` to make it case-insensitive.

Since you're repeating the same pattern 3 times, I've grouped it and used the `{3}` quantifier rather than writing it out 3 times.

Comment: A smarter way than I thought. Thanks +1

Comment: Good one.  Unless I'm mistaken you don't need the `?:`

Comment: @AbraCadaver Right. I'm so used to using the `$match` argument.